# Can't open Nautilus file explorer with shortcut + not appearing on Firefox download window

Tags: shortcut-keys, nautilus, firefox, 22.04

Similar problems exist but don't match my problem.

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. It was a clean install. It seems that I can't do Windows key + E to open file explorer, It did work until very recently. Also, on Firefox, the download window, the one asking you where you want to save doesn't open. I'm pretty sure these events are linked to a same problem but I don't have any idea.

I would appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows  + E shortcut doesn't open Nautilus for me on 22.04, either. I haven't tried it on a previous version of Ubuntu, so I can't say much about that, but if you go into Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > View and Customize Shortcuts > Launchers, you can add it to the Home Folder shortcut which is disabled on my system.

As for the Firefox download window, I *think* that's not a bug, but a feature. In Firefox > Settings > General > Files and Applications > Downloads, you can select the folder where you want downloads to go, or set it to always ask you, which should bring back the dialog.

Comment: Noted for the shortcut. Thanks. But for Firefox, nope, I changed to "Always ask" and the window doesn't show

Comment: Hmm... There are issues with Firefox, so this may be one. The other thing I'd check is in the Applications Section of the Firefox download settings to see if you have something set for the file type you're trying to download that would override the setting to ask.

Comment: I tried with a lot of different types, web pages, png/svg files, etc. I left all the settings by default by the way.

Comment: You're probably, right. It comes from Firefox. I tried with Chromium and Nautilus window works correctly.

Comment: Take a look at [these posts](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=22.04+download+firefox) regarding downloads and Firefox. I haven't finished looking through them to see if anyone has filed a bug report for whatever package it is that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
The problem is not to have a shortcut for Folders, but to have nautilus simply lauching. I still have Nautilus icon on the dock but it does not open the app.